# JavaScript: Why the recursion won't stop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, callback, settimeout

Why recursion won't stop if I wrap `foo++` in a `setTimeout`? I'm pretty sure that I'm missing out on a major JavaScript concept about **asynchronous** operations.

```js
let foo = 0;

const bar = () => {
  setTimeout(() => foo++);

  if (foo <= 2) {
    bar();
  }
}

bar();
```

Comment: The timeout callback will be executed *sometime later*, after the current function has finished. But it never finishes.

Comment: @deceze what does *it* refer to in **it never finishes**? Also, it's a known fact that a timeout callback always executes after sometime and I was rather looking for an in-depth explanation :)

Comment: *It* is your function, `bar`. Just blank out the contents of `setTimeout`, for all intents and purposes it's irrelevant what you pass to `setTimeout` here. Reading `bar` with that ignored, it's clear that it's simply an endless recursion, hence *it* never finishes.

Comment: @deceze Sorry to say but the explanation is highly vague, by suggesting to just ignore a line of code.

Comment: Well, again, for all intents and purposes, you *can* ignore that line of code and it won't make a difference.

Comment: @deceze the purpose the question asked is not to receive a suggestion to have a line of code ignored but to understand the reason behind it not working as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `bar()` it gets added to something called the [call stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack). The call stack is used to keep track of whereabouts we are in our script as we call and return from functions. When a function is called, it gets added to the call stack, and when it returns it gets popped off the call stack.

```
Stack:
- bar()
```

When `bar()` runs, it calls `setTimeout()` which gets added to the call stack.

The `setTimeout()` function kicks off a Web API and finishes/returns, popping it off the call stack. The Web API then waits 0ms (0ms as when no delay is passed to setTimeout it defaults as 0) and pushes/enqueues your `() => foo++` callback onto the something called the task queue.

```
Task queue: (front ---- back)
() => foo++
```

Tasks in the task queue are popped/dequeued off of the queue by the *event loop* only when the call stack is empty. This is important, as this means the above callback which increments `foo` will only be invoked once `bar()` has returned (thus popping it off the call stack), however, this never occurs, as `bar()` continues to call itself continuously as your if-condition will always be true, and as a result, will continue to add `bar()` to the call stack.

```
Stack:
- bar() // after first recursive call
- bar()
```

As you continue to call `bar()` in your recursive functions, your call stack begins to fill up, and so does your task queue:

```
Stack:
- bar() // after N recursive calls
...
- bar()
- bar()
```

As your call stack never has the opportunity to pop bar() off the stack, it continues to grow, giving you a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using global state and side effects and your problems go away -

```js
const delay =
 500

function bar (foo = 0)
{ if (foo > 2)
    return
  else
    setTimeout(_ => bar(foo + 1), delay)
  console.log(foo)
}

bar()
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put the recursion inside the setTimeout callback:

```js
let foo = 0;

const bar = () => {
  foo++;
  if (foo <= 2) setTimeout(bar);
};

bar();

console.log(foo); // Displays 3
```

Comment: Please don't post solutions blindly without even a dry run. It won't log 3 but 1 as `setTimeout` is **async** and foo would be logged before it's execution.

Comment: If you simply put the increment before the `bar()` call, that's already sufficient. Putting `bar` into a timeout or not is then rather moot.

Comment: I sure did test but in my console which gives me 3 :(

Comment: @MetallimaX believe me, it isn’t possible :) Please post a screenshot of the console in your answer.

Comment: @VinaySharma it is possible because I've entered my console.log() statement after the ending of the processing. But you are right if you do it in a script it will output before the ending of the "recursive" setTimeout.